# Summing values in table in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to sum values in a table in word. I want people to be able to add values to one column and the next column should add them together.  So it should look like the example below:

[image]

What I'm getting is this

[image]

```
Sub totalFlight()

    Dim theTable As Table
    Dim initialCell As Cell
    Dim theRow As Row
    
    Set theTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(2)
    Set firstValue = theTable.Cell(3, 7)
    Set initialCell = theTable.Cell(3, 8)
    
    initialCell.Select
    Selection.Text = firstValue

    For rowNum = 4 To theTable.Rows.Count

        theCell = theTable.Cell(rowNum, 8)
        theCellValue = theTable.Cell(rowNum, 7).Range.Text
        upperCell = theTable.Cell(rowNum - 1, 8).Range.Text
        
        theCell.Select
        Selection = theCellValue + upperCell
    
    Next
        
End Sub
```

I have set the form fields to only accept numerical values

Answer (score 1):

The `Text` property returns the plain, unformatted text of the range. It is a `String`. Coverting it to a number with `Val` before calculating.

Please refers to Microsoft document:

> [Range.Text property (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.text?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

```
    For rowNum = 4 To theTable.Rows.Count

        theCell = theTable.Cell(rowNum, 8)
        theCellValue = Val(theTable.Cell(rowNum, 7).Range.Text)
        upperCell = Val(theTable.Cell(rowNum - 1, 8).Range.Text)
        
        theCell.Select
        Selection = theCellValue + Val(upperCell)
    
    Next
```

[image]

Comment: That was what I was looking for!  Perfect!  I was trying ".Range.value"  Thank you!